# gcc and caching

Tags: c, caching, compiler-construction

I'm developing a C program and oddly as I update the source files I don't see any change in the resulting executable. Is it possible gcc stores a cached copy of the files and even if I compile I don't get the newer version of my executable? In this case how can I force the compiler to use the newly edited files?

I am compiling my code with the following:

```
# gcc -o myExecFileName source_file_1.c source_file2.c
```

Comment: What commands are you using to compile and link?

Comment: Are you saving the files before compiling them again?

Comment: It depends on how you are compiling ? Files one by one and then link everything ? Or giving gcc every files ?

Comment: @Wooble gcc -o myExecFileName source_file_1.c source_file2.c
@Mahesh yes, I've also tried to change the name of the functions but it hasn't worked.

Comment: OK, what do you mean by "I don't see any change in the resulting executable"? There is (for example) no reason its size should change.

Comment: For instance if I add a printf(...) it doesn't print out a bit.

Comment: If you delete the file prior to compilation (`rm myExecFileName`) does the compilation produce a new version of the binary?

Comment: @haunted are you running the executable like this `./myExecFileName`? have you called it something silly, like `test`?

Comment: @pmg: yes, it does.
@NeilButterworth I am running ./readMe

Comment: Delete your *.o files and compile again.

Comment: @haunted: is it `readMe` as per your latest comment or `myExecFileName` as per a previous comment. The `-o` parameter to `gcc` specifies the name of the binary. That is what you must call.

Comment: Ok, guys, I have the answer, me silly. I was compiling a copy of the source files located in a different directory. So I have been updating the original source files, but I have always compiled the copies that were unchanged. I should've checked the paths.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To answer your question, no gcc will not cache your files.  Something else is going on.  You are either changing files in a different directory as @Lee D suggests, or you are not saving the files before compiling, or perhaps the changes you are making are ifdef'd out.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like your makefile is out of whack. `make` uses file times to determine whether or not to run a compilation step. You have to have your dependencies in order for it to work correctly, though.

Observe:

```
hello: hello.c
   $(CC) hello.c -o hello
```

On the first line, `hello: hello.c` means look at the timestamp on the file `hello.c`, and if it's older than the timestamp on `hello` (or if `hello` doesn't exist), then run the compliation specified below.

Comment: From the comments it seems he isn't even using a makefile.

Comment: Answered before the comments appeared -- but i'm leaving it because it's the most likely helpful solution to people who arrive here from Google.

Comment: I wasn't using a makefile... I tried to make one, it compiles but... nothing has really changed. Has my compiler gone crazy?!?

Comment: Try deleting your old executable before building the new one. It shouldn't make a difference, but it should make your problem more obvious.

Answer (score 0):

Check to make sure you are editing the same files you are compiling. If you are working with multiple versions of files in multiple windows, that might not be the case. Happened to me last week.